# Simple cycle and wrong element

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Here`s some code:

```
foreach (int[] temp in intList)
{
    string str = GenerateGamma(0,1,10,temp);
    if (str == "924890128")
        answer.Add(temp);
}
```

Where in `intList` there are int arrays and each one of them has the following property: `array[1] = 1`(length of array is 10). Well, when I looked in `answer`, then I saw the array `1 4 6 0 9 3 2 7 5 8`, so `array[1] = 4`. 
Here is code of `GenerateGamma()`.

```
public static string GenerateGamma(int i0, int j0, int m, int[] b)
{
    Constants ct = new Constants();
    int[] gamma = new int[9];
    int[] inside_array = b;
    string result = "";
    int temp_i = i0, temp_j = j0, inttemp = 0;
    for (int t = 1; t <= 9; t++)
    {
        temp_i = ((temp_i + 1) % m);
        temp_j = ((temp_j + inside_array[temp_i]) % m);
        inttemp = inside_array[temp_i];
        inside_array[temp_i] = inside_array[temp_j];
        inside_array[temp_j] = inttemp;
        gamma[t-1] = (inside_array[(inside_array[temp_i]+inside_array[temp_j])%m]%m);
    }
    result = string.Join("",gamma);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Show GenerateGamma method.

Comment: I add the method`s code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are reference types, if you change passed array inside `GenerateGamma()` method the original array will be changed too.

Your array is changed because inside method you have:

```
int[] inside_array = b;
```

Here you don't create a copy of passed array, you just create copy of reference to array. So, you have one array and two references (`b` and `inside_array`) which point to the same array: `b[0] = 1;` and `inside_array[0] = 1;` do the same - they modify the same array.

If you want copy:

```
int[] inside_array = new int[b.Length];
for (int a = 0; a < inside_array.Length; a++)
{
    inside_array[a] = b[a];
}
```

After this you will have two arrays and when you change one array another one won't be changed.